# Sending Tab during the click event of a button inside the header of the tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to delete the tab on click of a button(TabCloseButton) inside the tabitem header. but i can't get the tab as parent too. Can anyone help me find out how to pass the tab to the click method. Any code sample will be helpful.

```
<TabControl Name="ConnectionsTab" BorderThickness="0" Background="White">
<TabControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
 <Setter.Value>
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
 <Grid Background="White">
 <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="#1b9ed2" Margin="6,0,12,0" Background="White">
 <ContentPresenter Height="30" x:Name="ContentSite" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,15,5,-5">
 </ContentPresenter>
 </Border>
 <Button Background="Wheat" BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="TabCloseButton" Click="TabCloseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="Close" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Padding="0">
 <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Close" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
 </Button>
 </Grid>
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 ...............
 </ControlTemplate>
 </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
 </Style>
 </TabControl.Resources>
 <TabItem Header="Connections" IsSelected="True" TabIndex="0">
 <TabItem.Content>
 <Grid>
 <TextBlock Name="errorMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray" Visibility="Hidden"></TextBlock>
 <Grid Name="MainConnectionTab"/>
 </Grid>
 </TabItem.Content>
 </TabItem>
 <TabItem Header="machine1"></TabItem>
 <TabItem Header="machine2"></TabItem>
 </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper method that uses the `VisualTreeHelper` to find the parent `TabItem` in the visual tree:

```
private void TabCloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button tabCloseButton = (Button)sender;
    TabItem parentTab = FindParent<TabItem>(tabCloseButton);
    if (parentTab != null)
        ConnectionsTab.Items.Remove(parentTab);

}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    T parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```